# Atlas on sphere $S^n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Prove that there does not exist an atlas of the sphere $S^n\subset R^{n+1}$ with exactly one chart.

Update Solution:

Suppose there is an atlas with only one chart to cover $S^n$. By definition, there exists a homeomorphism between an open subset $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $S^n$. Since $S^n$ is compact while any open $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is not, that is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: $S^n$ is not diffeomorphic to any open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since it is compact and open sets are not (every diffeo- is homeomorphism also).

If spaces $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic, then $A$ is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ $B$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks @Antonie, but can u show more details?. I think we will suppose that exist atlas with only one chart and prove it's preposterous.

Comment: @Hoang Edited, now it's just a hint;) (and you are thinking in a right way)